# Is it discouraged to save the same piece of data in two places in a relational database?

Tags: database, django, django-models, relational-database

I am in the process of writing a Django/Python based app and I want to avoid writing code or making more requests to my DB than I have to. Would it be unreasonable to store a piece of data already stored at a higher level in a lower level so that it is easier to access from the lower level?

Hopefully that was clear - please tell me if you need clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: DRY doesn't just apply to code, you know.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication

Comment: Is the problem that the information should only be stored at the lower level and not at the higher level?

Comment: FYI, this technique is called 'denormalization'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be useful to partially denormalize a database if the calculations required are extremely lengthy or complex, but it should only be done after other attempts to optimize have had little or no success, and only sparingly.

Answer (score 2):

Besides denormalization, there are other ways to improve query performance.  The first step, of course, is to actually measure your code's performance.  Just because a join query doesn't scale up very easily doesn't mean it's a bad idea to use them.  Not every website has the request-load to require ultra-optimized request handling.

[In fact, Cal Henderson has calculated that all but 100 websites are *not* in the top 100 most visited websites.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6Fr65PFqfk)

If it turns out your well thought out and very mantainable queries are actually a bottleneck (even if you're not necessarily  in the top 100, maybe you are in the top 1,000,000), the first step is to take a really good look at the actual queries that are bottlenecks.  Sometimes adding or removing indexes in the right place, or just keeping the database tidy (`VACUUM` or `ANALYZE` commands) on a scehdule can make the difference.

A next step is to look for caching opportunities.  A significant percentage of typical sites perform the same queries over and over for every page and user, and they don't change very quickly.  Stashing oft-used data in a cache (memcache, for instance) will take some burden off of the database server.

While we're on the subject of database *servers*, make sure that the machine hosting the database is free to respond to queries, instead of performing any other work.  Databases are among the hardest technology to scale out, so to get the most out of it, make sure your database is running on a machine with loads of ram, fast disks and no other responsibilities. Put the web-app server on its own machine, put the static files on another machine, let the firewall live on a separate machine.  The query cache can go on its own machine.

Just because databases are hard to scale out (though easy to scale up), it is not impossible.  If two tables are rarely used in the same query, they can be split across two devices.  If the join conditions of a certain set of tables are always the same (like UserID's), then rows can be split across multiple servers (this is called sharding).

Once you've really exhausted all of these options, denormalization is probably the next step.  It seems simple, but there's a few reasons why this is so late in the steps you want to take.

The biggest is because it's actually hard to keep the duplicated data right.  If no data is duplicated, then there can't be a conflict, but if data does get duplicated and one portion of the app doesn't carefully update both places, then different queries will return different, conflicting results.  good choices when denromalizing your data can make out of sync conditions minor (just rebuild the denormalized data from the authoritative source), but it always increases the code maintenance work you will have to do.

The second is because denormalization isn't neccesarily a speed-up.  Much like adding indexes, it trades write performance for read performance.  If you actually do a decent number of writes, it will actually make the average performance *slower*.  Unlike adding indexes, databases can't tell you when you need denormalization;  It is always a guess.

Finally, when you do decide to go with denormalization, be aware of what your ORM (if you use one, since this is a django question you probably do) is really doing.  Make sure you are designing your queries to give you only the data you actually use, and make sure your ORM isn't helpfully pulling more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very discouraged.

That violates the point of having a rdbms. Which copy of data should be updated if it were to change? There are many, many ways to avoid it. Django has a cache system for intensive queries. You can also write views in the database that make retrieving data less comples. Also, writing methods for your models will probably help you retrieve data with more ease.

I would look at Model-View-Controller designs as well. If it is not set up well, your application can become chaotic.